# about android linkify for maps

Tags: android, linkify

I am using `linkify` in my android app to auto recognize addresses. It works with some addresses but not others. One of the things that I noticed was that capitalization is an important thing for the address to be recognized. Spelling is also important. However, even with these, I have not being able to auto recognize all addresses.

Can anyone kindly provide more insight as to what should an address look like to be auto recognized by `linkify` ?

Thanks.